# custom actions in windows installer

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

I want to make some things clear to me.
Are custom actions that call assembly methods are executed inside of the deferred InstalledExecuteSequence? Even if so, why shouldn't I gather information using UI in my CA?

Answer (score 1):

I would read:

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm)